# Application doesn't work after sourcecode

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app, platypus

I have a working Python+Tkinter program working which is a dictionary creator. However, when I convert soucecode into app, program itself doesn't create the file it is supposed to create. I am quite new to programming, and I would appreciate if you could help me. So far I have tried py2app and platypus both give the same result.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import itertools
import string

def done():
    l=list()
    if check_a.get() == True:
        l.append(string.lowercase)

    if check_A.get() == True:
        l.append(string.uppercase)

    if check_0.get() == True:
        l.append(string.digits)
    l=''.join(l)
    n=entryvar.get()
    with open("b.txt","a+") as f:
        for i in itertools.product(l,repeat=n):
            f.write(''.join(list(i)))
            f.write('\n')
        f.close()

generater=Tk()
generater.title("Generater")
generater.geometry("450x300+200+200")

mainlabel=Label(generater).pack()

entryvar=IntVar()
entry=Entry(generater, textvariable=entryvar).pack()

check_a=BooleanVar()
check_A=BooleanVar()
check_0=BooleanVar()
checkBox_a=Checkbutton(generater, variable=check_a, text="a-z").pack()
checkBox_A=Checkbutton(generater, variable=check_A, text="A-Z").pack()
checkBox_0=Checkbutton(generater, variable=check_0, text="0-9").pack()

DoneButton=Button(generater, text="Done", command=done).pack()





generater.mainloop()
```

Comment: As a side note, don't store the result of a call to `pack()` in a variable. This method always return None, not a reference to the widget.

Comment: You day it doesn't create the file it's suppsed to create. What files _does_ it create instead? Wrong name? Wrong folder?

Answer (score 4):

When you start an application created by py2app the current working directory is changed to the 'Contents/Resources' folder inside the application bundle. Because your script creates a file relative to the current working directory it ends up inside the application.

(For examples a myapp.app/Contents/Resources/b.txt)

Comment: I have tried py2app again and i looked inside the app bundle and searched "b.txt" on hard-driver, still find nothing